# raspberry connect wifi by python

Tags: python, wifi, raspberry-pi3

How can I configure WiFi using Python on Raspberry Pi3 (raspbian)?

I tried python's subprocess:

```
os.popen("sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid my_ssid key s:pass")
```

But this command disables my WiFi interface (wlan0) so I have a `no wifi interfaces found` in the Raspbian top panel.
I also tried to use a module named [wifi](https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I get the same result of `wlan0` interface being disabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"""
Name             : Python Connect to Wifi for Linux
Created By       : Agus Makmun (Summon Agus)
Blog             : bloggersmart.net - python.web.id
License          : GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 3, 29 June 2007
Documentation    : https://github.com/agusmakmun/Some-Examples-of-Simple-Python-Script/
Powered          : Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7
"""

import os, sys

print "[+] Enter this some Option"
print " 1. Active Wifi (up)\n 2. Down Wifi (down)\n 3. Exit"
inp_up_down = raw_input("[+] Enter choice number: ")
if inp_up_down == '1':
    os.system("ifconfig wlan0 up")
    print " Are you want connect to wifi?"
    print " 1. Yes, Conncet\n 2. No, Exit"
    inp_connect = raw_input("[+] Enter your choice: ")
    if inp_connect == '1':
        os.system("iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID")
        masuk = raw_input("Enter name of wifi (ex: @wifi.id): ")
        os.system("iwconfig wlan0 essid "+masuk)
        os.system("dhclient wlan0")
    elif inp_connect == '2':
    print "Thankyou.."
        sys.exit()
elif inp_up_down == '2':
    os.system("ifconfig wlan0 down")
elif inp_up_down == '3':
    sys.exit()
else:
    print "Sorry, Wrong Input!!"
```

Comment: I found my solution editing wpa_supplicant.conf opening and editing the file by python. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Comment: You may want to post your solution as an answer.